# PackageNotInstalledError when I try to update conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I tried to install a package with `conda` and I got a `Segmentation fault`. The package was `pyTorch`  but I dont think the problem is package specific. I tried then to update my `conda` hoping for a quick fix but that fails as well with the following error:

```
conda update conda

PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: /home/user_name/anaconda3/envs/my_proj
  package name: conda
```

I have seen similar cases for other users here on SO and some people recommend the following (which also gives me a segmentation error)

```
conda update   --name base  conda
Solving environment: - Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Also, in case that helps:

```
conda list    --name base  conda
# packages in environment at /home/user_name/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anaconda                  5.3.1                    py37_0
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0
anaconda-navigator        1.9.2                    py37_0
anaconda-project          0.8.2                    py37_0
conda                     4.5.12                   py37_0
conda-build               3.15.1                   py37_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1
```

Does anyone know how I can fix my anaconda environment please. My Python applications run fine, it is only when I try to install a new package with `conda` that the problem arises.

Thanks!

Comment: Does `conda install -n base -c defaults conda=4.7.12` work?

Comment: @merv That gives the same segmentation fault error

Comment: Okay. Perhaps try running in verbose mode (using `-vv` or `-vvv` flags) to get more specific info on where it fails. Otherwise, I'd recommend posting as [a Conda GitHub Issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues).